# Making a readonly input but not editable from programmer tools

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I'm filling a input with session value, so it goes `value="$session['name']"` and i want to make this input not editable, **but** by using programmer tools you can easily change `value` and the same goes with `readonly`/`document.getElementById('inputID').readOnly = true;` and on input.

What can i do so it becomes "impossible" to edit?

Comment: Anything in an `input` tag is going to be editable on the client side - anything in HTML at all will be. If you can't trust user input then you'll need to store things server side instead.

Comment: @iainn In this case what would be the best solution? Since the session is always different... but by puttin server side with will fill `value` so its back to square 1

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Everything you receive from client may be replaced by other person.

The only thing you can do - make strong crypto hash to sign your value in this field and if you received content, that doesn't satisfy this hash - reject this.

Comment: I understand but can u do a example? Im a bit new to php/javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, anything user see on client side in HTML, it is editable. 
To prevent this you must store the values at server side in `sessions` or using other mechanisms.
 From the question I guess you already have the value in sessions then you can use that directly on the next execution.

Comment: In this case what would be the best solution? Since the session is always different... but by puttin server side with will fill value so its back to square 1

Comment: If you want to keep the value same for every sessions store it in database or a single file on server side.

Comment: but see this way, after that all being done, to fill the input you have to `value=?` right? So it's back to square 1

Comment: Why do you want to fill the input ? Is it for showing to the user or is it to submit the data in database?

Comment: submit, it's a input, otherwise would be a label or paragraph

Comment: But why submit somthing that can't be changed?

Comment: Are you submitting the form to any external site?

Answer (score -4):

You can use something different than an input then.

You could try to print your value in a paragraph tag

```
<p><?php echo $session['name'] ?></p>
```

In all cases, the user can submit whatever he wants via a POST request tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

Edit : Bad wording, It looked like I said a paragraph was impossible to edit but that's absolutely not what I meant :)

Comment: `document.designMode = "on"` or `document.querySelector("p").contentEditable = true`

Comment: Really? `$('p').html('new session name');`

Comment: Edited my answer as my sentence was not reflecting what I meant